# PicketLnkSTS and sender vouches confirmation method

Tags: saml

I need some information on how to issue security token with sender-vouches subject confirmation method in a picketlink STS service.
I have searched for informations and examples but i didn't find anything useful, i don't even know if picketlink (token providers and login-module) support such tokens!

I need this kind of authentication/authorization system for a project i am working on where a subject logs in to web application and the resulting indentity must be propagated to the a SOAP web service deployed on an other server.

I would like to use standard solution for this scenario avoiding the implementation of proprietary solutions and "SAML STS profile" seems to do the trick, any other ideas?

Thank you all